# How to get information with python when data is heavily nested

Tags: python, parsing, text, text-mining

I have a text file which contains some data to be mined.

The structure is shown below

```
name (personA {
    field1 : data1
    field2 : data2
    fieldN : dataN
    subfield() {
        fieldx1 : datax1
        fieldxN : dataxN
        }
    }
   name (personB {
    field1 : data11
    field2 : data12
    fieldN : data1N
    }
```

In some person's record the subfield is absent and output should specify subfield to be unknown in that case. Now below is the code I use to extract the data

```
import re
data = dict()
with open('data.txt', 'r') as fin:
    FLAG, FLAGP, FLAGS = False, False, False
    for line in fin:
        if FLAG:
            if re.search('field1', line):
                d1 = line.split()[2]
                data['field1'] = d1
            if re.search('fieldN', line):
                dN = line.split()[2]
                data['fieldN'] = dN
                data['fieldxn'] = 'unknown'
                FLAGP = True
        if FLAGS:
            if re.search('fieldxN', line):
                dsN = line.split()[2]
                data['fieldxn'] = dsN

        if re.search('name\ \(', line):
            pn = line.split()[1]
            FLAG = True
            data['name'] = pn
        if re.search('subfield', line):
            FLAGS = True
        if len(data) == 4:
           if FLAGP:
               print data
               FLAGP = False
               FLAG = False
               FLAGS = False
```

The output is shown below

```
{'field1': 'data1', 'fieldN': 'dataN', 'name': '(personA', 'fieldxn': 'unknown'}
{'field1': 'data11', 'fieldN': 'data1N', 'name': '(personB', 'fieldxn': 'unknown'}
```

The problem has been that I don't know where to print data so current I am using below statment to print data which is wrong

```
if len(data) == 4:
    if FLAGP:
       print data
       FLAGP = False
       FLAG = False
       FLAGS = False
```

I would appreciate if someone could give any suggestion to retrieve the data correctly

Comment: What you are trying to archive is not text mining but parsing a format. What do you know about the data format? What is the data source?

Comment: Although they are not altogether easy to learn to use, one of the best ways of processing input like this involves the use of so-called scannerless (or lexerless) parsers such as pyparsing (see http://infohost.nmt.edu/~shipman/soft/pyparsing/web/index.html). With this software you could, for instance, set the default value of 'subfield' to `None` during parsing and then catch that value during subsequent processing.

Comment: @BillBell Thanks for the pointer, I will take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a different approach to parsing, storing the subfields (and other fields) in a dictionary.

```
data = open('data.txt', 'rt').read()

### Given a string containing lines of "fieldX : valueY" 
### return a dictionary of values
def getFields(field_data):
    fields = {}
    if (field_data != None):
        field_lines = field_data.strip().split("\n")
        for pair in field_lines:
            name, value = pair.split(":")
            fields[name.strip()] = value.strip()
    return fields


### Split the data by name
people_data = data.strip().split("name (")[1:]

### Loop though every person record
for person_data in people_data:
    name, person_data = person_data.split(" {", 1)   # split the name and the fields
    # Split out the subfield data, if any
    subfield_data = None
    if (person_data.find("subfield()") > -1):
        field_data, subfield_data = person_data.split("subfield() {", 1)
        subfield_data = subfield_data.split("}")[0]
    # Separate the fields into single lines of pairs
    fields = getFields(field_data)
    # and any subfields
    subfields = getFields(subfield_data)

    print("Person: "+str(name))
    print("Fields: "+str(fields))
    print("Sub_Fields:"+str(subfields))
```

Which gives me:

```
Person: personA
Fields: {'field1': 'data1', 'field2': 'data2', 'fieldN': 'dataN'}
Sub_Fields:{'fieldx1': 'datax1', 'fieldxN': 'dataxN'}
Person: personB
Fields: {'field1': 'data1', 'field2': 'data2', 'fieldN': 'dataN'}
Sub_Fields:{}
```

So you could just adjust your output based on whether subfields was `None`, or otherwise.  The idea is to get your data input into more flexible structures, rather than "brute-force" parsing like you have done.  In the above I use `split()` a lot to give a more flexible way through, rather than relying on finding exact names.  Obviously it depends on your design requirements too.